# Given $\left|e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}\left(e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}-e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}}\right)\right|$ show that it's equal to $2|\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}|$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given $\left|e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}\left(e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}-e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}}\right)\right|$ I want to show that it's equal to $2\left|\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}\right|.$

My work.

$|e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}(e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}-e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}})|=|(\cos\frac{\phi}{2}+i\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}})(2i\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}})|=|\sin\phi i - 2\sin^2{\frac{\phi}{2}}|$.

How from here go on to show that it's equal to $2|\sin{\frac{\phi}{2}}|?$

Answer (score 2):

$|e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}(e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}-e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}})|=|e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}|\times|e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}-e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}}|$.

$|e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}|=1$.

Use identity $e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}=2i\sin\phi$.

$|e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}-e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}}|=|2i\sin\frac{\phi}{2}|=2|\sin\frac{\phi}{2}|$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this answers my question.

Comment: Don't use `\text{sin}` use just `\sin`. The text version spaces things wrong.

Comment: This is a good answer (+1). For multiplication you can also use \cdot or \times instead of *

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm new here, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from $|i\sin\phi - 2\sin^2{\frac{\phi}{2}}|$ we have $$\sqrt{\sin^2\phi + 4\sin^4\frac{\phi}{2}} = \sqrt{4\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}\cos^2\frac{\phi}{2} + 4\sin^4\frac{\phi}{2}} = \sqrt{4\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}(\cos^2\frac{\phi}{2} + \sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}}) = \sqrt{4\sin^2\frac{\phi}{2}} = 2|\sin \frac{\phi}{2}|$$